# How to return the length and value of a selection in a datalist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-datalist

I would like to fabricate some code, that tracks the amount of unfiltered options in a datalist. So how could I keep track of this?

Secondly when there is only one option left in the list I want to access the value of this option.

Here is a link to the w3c spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-datalist-element

Note: I want to use the datalist, so I don't want to create my own filter on the datalist and get the values from there.

I came up with this code so far:

**Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/6usf7j9g/

**html**

```
<h3>Anything you'd like?</h3>
<input id="your-favourite" list="choices"/>
<datalist id="choices">
  <option value="Laphroaig"></option>
  <option value="Jameson"></option>
  <option value="Talisker"></option>
  <option value="Oban"></option>
  <option value="Dalwhinnie"></option>
  <option value="Glennfidich"></option>
  <option value="Glenlivet"></option>
</datalist>
```

**jQuery/js**

```
var selectedChoices = null; //in this variable I need to know how many items are left in the list after filtering. If you type "Glen" it should be two, if you type "Glenn", "J", etc. it should give a value of 1. It only needs to work on google chrome.

$("#your-favourite").on("keyup", function(){
    selectedChoices = null; //PART OF THE ISSUE: Should change the value of the variable here, depending on the options that are showing.
  if(selectedChoices === 1){
    let finalOption = "unknown"; //PART OF THE ISSUE: Should load the value of the remaining option
    // validate success
    alert("There is only one value left in the list! It is called: " + finalOption);
    selectedChoices = null; // reset value to 0.
  }
    // log the datalist and input elements, it might have some info that helps finding a solution.   
  console.log($("#your-favourite"));
  console.log($("#choices"));
}); // end on keyup
```

Comment: Simple, your filter probably will render some of the items inthe list, some will not be rendered, rendered ones will be visible and others not if i udnerstand you right, count the numbers .. works for you?

Comment: Have you tried to use the methods like for select list?

Comment: @burhancerit If you could tell me how to detect the ones the options display after filtering in the datalist, that would be a great way in the right direction.

Comment: @reporter What specific methods are you talking about? Also if you mean the `<select>` tag. I want to do this with datalists. The list could be about a hundred items long, so I definitely need the filtering a datalist provides.

Comment: I understand what you want to do, but I don't see any way of doing it natively.

Comment: I missunderstand some comments, due to occurence of horizontal scollbar.

Comment: i have read the source code of datalist and it looks like they are doing same indexOf stuff in the list, and push the items into a stack when they find a match, and return them. However what you need might not be possible :(,  But somebody already implemented something close to what you need,

 
    if($('#choices option').filter(function(){
        
        return this.value === val;        
    }).length) {
        alert(this.value);
    }
this will return the values of selected item in the list when ever you pick one..

Or you have to implement your own code :D

Comment: Plus my own implementation would look like this,

if i know the list already then i can do the same thing (datalist do) when we  have a action event, iterate over the list and find the matching ones with if(list[i].indexOf(value_typed)>0){ matchingListArray.push(list[i]); }, similar one could help you.. OFC this would be really inefficient code

Comment: @burnhancerit Thanks for looking into this all the way down to the sourcecode. Where did you find the sourcecode of datalists by the way? It would be interesting to look through. Your solution of iterating over the `#choices option`'s would work and offer more flexibility than using the datalist. I would like to keep using the datalist tough.